# PySpark: Partition a dataframe based on column values and store the resulting dataframes in a list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, k-means

I have a pyspark dataframe with 4 columns: city, season, weather_variable, variable_value. I have to partition the frame into partition for different combinations of city, season, weather_variable. Following which, I'll apply k-means on these partitions.

I'm using the following code in order to create the partitions:

```py
a = df_in.select('city', 'season', 'variable').distinct().toPandas().as_matrix()
dfArray = [df_in.filter("city = '{}' and season = '{}' and variable = '{}'".format(x[0], x[1], x[2])) for x in a]
```

But the issue is the process is very slow as it is using filter iteratively. Can someone suggest a way to make the process more efficient. Something like groupby might help.

Please find below the python version of the code that I want to convert to pyspark:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def k_means_on_partition(group):

    v = group['variable_value']
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 7)

    kmeans.fit(v.values.reshape(-1, 1)) 
    group['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_

    return group


df_out = df_in.groupby(['city', 'season', 'variable']).apply(k_means_on_partition)
```

Also, for pyspark, I'll be using pyspark.ml instead of sklearn.

Comment: you could just read the dataframe and write it back to parquet with the `partitionBy` attribute. Then you could specify the column that have to be considered for the partitioning. Finally you get one folder per partition

Comment: @gaw writing and reading the files will also make it slow as I'll have around 5200 partitions. PS: I've updated the question adding more details.